# Laravel 5.3 get belongsToMany and count pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, has-many

I have next models:

```
class Polling extends Model
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function participants()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class, 'participant_poll', 'poll_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function results()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Participant::class, 'poll_results', 'poll_id');
    }
}

class Participant extends Model
{
    public function polls()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Polling::class);
    }

    public function results()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Polling::class);
    }

}
```

**poll_results** - pivot table have structure: id, poll_id, participant_id.
I need view next table:

```
№|participant.name|Count vote|
1|Mike            |15        |
2|................|10        |
..............................
```

Count vote get pivot table *poll_results.*
Help please, write  query.

```
$poll = Polling::first();
$poll->participants()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method.

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models

Your query would look like this one:

```
Participant::withCount('polls')->get();
```

This will add new property to results called `polls_count`

Comment: This return participants count (get participant table). Column Count vote - need get  from poll_results table.